# If girl is touched by non-mehram mistakenly, will it be counted in sin?

Tags: quran, sunnah, reference-request, non-mahram

I have this question so please answer with the help of hadees or ayaah let me know about it.
If girl is touched by a non-mehram mistakenly, will it be counted as a sin?

I will be very thankful to you for this act of kindness Allah subhan u taalah will reward you for this

Comment: Just think about it. Will it be a fair religion if the above-mentioned action is a sin? No need for a source. Just use common sense.

Comment: If by accident you kill someone, will you be blamed for the murder. If by accident you have a full course meal while your fasting will you be blamed...NAH. Plus in my humble opinion, I think it had to touch an individual of the opposite sex without the thought of lust or any un-Islamic intension, then your alright...if not then ofc you should be reminding of the hadith where prophet mentioned it's better to be shaped with iron or smth then touch a women. Ofc its just my opinion and Allah knows best!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you get sin for doing something unintentionally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60802/do-you-get-sin-for-doing-something-unintentionally)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from 'A Code of Ethics for Muslim Men and Women'

200 – Rule: Bodily contact that happens in busy places (such as markets, processions, Salat al-Jumu‘ah, funerals, the Sanctuaries (haram) of the A’immah (Peace be upon all of them), and the House of Allah سُبْحَانَهُ وَ تَعَالَى in an unintentional way between a non-Mahram man and woman is not a problem, with the condition that one does not go to these places with the purpose and intention of being touched. ABGKMST

It is clear from the ruling above, provided that a person is not deliberately putting themselves in a situation where they can be mistakenly touched in order to gain pleasure from it then they are blameless.

Allah knows our true intent and will surely judge us according to them. So if it is unintentional it is not a sin.

Comment: Please provide references for your answers. As of now they sound like giving Fatwas (no offence)!

Comment: Idk if it's important...but imo we should clarify that the idea of "touch" is to seek sexual desires from it...