# Do you get sin for doing something unintentionally?

Tags: sin, islamic-basis

As-salamu Alaykum,

If you have sinned without the intention to sin, are you still held accountable? does it depend on the sin?

Jazak Allah Khair

Answer (score 2):

You do not earn sin for unintentionally committing a sinful act. The evidence for this includes:

> #### ربنا لا تؤاخذنا إن نسينا أو أخطأنا
>
> Our Lord, do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:286](http://quran.com/2/286) ; see [hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/739860)</sup>
>
> #### وليس عليكم جناح فيما أخطأتم به ولكن ما تعمدت قلوبكم
>
> And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only for] what your hearts intended.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:5](http://quran.com/33/5)</sup>
>
> #### إن الله وضع عن أمتي الخطأ والنسيان وما استكرهوا عليه
>
> Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do.
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1321240)</sup>

Note however that you may still be liable to some expiation e.g. you need to make corrections for mistakes in acts of worship like prayer and hajj and you need to compensate other people for injuries and damages.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense