# unintentionally looking at haram

Tags: halal-haram, waswasa

asalam alaykum.

i am on the internet a lot (watching halal things) but sometimes a haram clip or ad might show up in the video or on a website and as soon as i realize it is there i look away from it since i don't want to do a sin. but i feel guilty as if i did something wrong even though i didn't, i am always getting waswasah that you did haram even though it was unintentional. please someone help me how do i get rid of these waswasah that are telling me that i did haram even though it was a mistake.

Comment: Also see [Do you get sin for doing something unintentionally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60802/)

Answer (score 2):

Alsalam alekom,
First of all you must know you didn't do anything wrong.

> Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him, said:
> “O Ali, do not follow the gaze for the first, and you do not have the
> second one.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi 2701 and it is in “Sahih
> al-Jami’” (7953).

He said in al-Tuhfa: “His saying: (Do not follow the gaze with the gaze) is from following, that is, do not follow it, and do not make another after the first. ".
Thus it becomes clear to you that deliberately looking at a non-mahram woman, as well as continuing to look after a sudden look, is forbidden.
We ask God to protect us and you from all other taboos, and God is the Guide to the straight path.

So about the **waswasah** there are things that should help you in that

1. Keep reading the Holy Quran.
2. Preserving the morning and evening remembrances (adhkars), and the remembrances (adhkars) of sleeping and waking up from it.
3. seeking refuge in Allah- from the accursed Satan and his temptations.
4. beneficial actions that bring the you closer to allah.

I hope my answer can be useful in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to try and combat waswas. You could increase the amount of dhikr you do. Recite morning and evening adhkars and read more Quran to help build a stronger connection to Allah. By doing these things you gain a stronger bond with Allah and Shaytaan finds it harder to come to you and play these mind games on you. I pray Allah helps you with your waswas and keep you protected from shaytaan.

Comment: thank you, i will try these.

Comment: You’re welcome :)