# Touching A girl's behind by mistake

Tags: sin, women

Salam walikum
I have a question.

So I'm a high school student and our hallways are very crowded and people are at their lockers and I have situations where by mistake my private area touches the back area of a sister is this a sin?

Comment: An unintentional mistake is not blameworthy as a sin, see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60802/ However intermingling of males and females in the first place is a sin. You should take steps which prevent such a situation from arising.

Answer (score 2):

Accidental physical contact between a Muslim male and a female is not a sin by itself, as long as it is not intentional, frequent, or accompanied by any sexual desire or pleasure. However, we should still be careful and cautious in such situations, and try to avoid them as much as possible. we should also seek Allah’s forgiveness and protection from any evil consequences that may result from such contact.

Allah says in the Quran:

> “Say: O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful.” (39:53)

And the Prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> “Allah is more pleased with the repentance of His servant than one of you would be on finding his camel which he had lost in the desert.” (Hadith Bukhari 6309)

Repentance is a great blessing and mercy from Allah, and He accepts the repentance of those who turn to Him sincerely and regretfully.
And Allah knows best.

Comment: If it's not a sin, why seek forgiveness?

Comment: In Islam, an unintentional mistake is not blameworthy as a sin. However, seeking forgiveness is still important because it is a way to show remorse and to ask for Allah’s mercy and guidance. The Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) sought forgiveness from Allah more than seventy times a day. The Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) was not a sinner.